# django dynamic form with a print between the fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm doing a dynamic form with django and I need to write something between the fields. Here is the code:

```
class WayForm(forms.Form):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):         
        waysNumber = kwargs.pop("waysNumber")
        super(WayForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        CHOICES = (('1','Pista',),('2','Corriol',))            
        for i in range(waysNumber):

            # a label or something to print the WaysNumber and show it to the template

            self.fields["Descripcio"+str(i)]= forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(),label="Descripcio"+str(i))
            self.fields["Tipus"+str(i)] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=CHOICES, label="Tipus de camí"+str(i))
```

it can be done here or I have to do in the template? And how I do it? Thanks!

Comment: is this code working?

Comment: yes, but for the moment it only works with get method